# How to add shortcode to blogspot?

Tags: jquery, css, blogger, shortcode, blogspot

Is it possible to create shortcodes in blogger?
Something like:

```
[item]contents[/item]
```

or

```
[img class='someClass']yourimagelink[/img]
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUndjBROwSM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thanks. Ive already seen that but it doesn't seem to be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **it depends**

- for pieces that *augment features of content present on the page*, or if you don't care about SEO and are convinced that `[img src=a class=b]` is better than `<img src="a" class="b">`, **yes, it's possible** eg see [Blogger shortcode plugin](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/04/blogger-shortcode-plugin.html) or create your own with [shortcode.js](http://nicinabox.com/shortcode.js/).
- for important pieces of *content* that should be indexed **no, it's not possible**.

If you're interested in why, here's the long answer:

To access a webpage, you have servers and their **pre-**[browser-load]-**processing** languages (PHP, ASP, Ruby, Perl..), and clients (browsers) with their languages (Java-, Type-, & Actionscript). Search engines rely on code sent by the server evidently because only humans need a browser to query a page. 
As with many free hosts (freewebs, wix, ..), you do not have direct access to the server-side code in Blogger, but you can modify the XHTML-like template with custom tags like Blogger's `<b:include>`, which behind the scenes probably makes a call to `<?php include() ?>` or similar. This leaves us client-side scripting as only alternative.

While the shortcode blogger plugin mimics the Wordpress shortcodes, it is built in Javascript and therefore of no use to [traditional] search engines.

Reportedly, [Google could access some Javascript contents](http://moz.com/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really) by using the Chrome browser as an extension of its search engine (so it is rumored). However, the page linked to shows mixed success results. **It's not because you can understand some words in a song that you can necessarily make sense of it**: even if search engines index it, they won't necessarily do it *correctly*. It also begs the question: if 90% of your visitors access the website from another browser, how will Google get enough data to make sense of your dynamic content?

If you have a look at the [Blogger shortcode plugin](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/04/blogger-shortcode-plugin.html), you will also notice that what it enables are basic CSS-styled elements, and third-party embeds, which you can usually copy-paste an embed-code from to your page in HTML view. And as a personal note, I would say: why use shortcodes like `[image class=x]` when that's exactly the same as doing `<img class="x">`?

**Conclusion:** don't use shortcodes and stay on Blogger, or get hosting with a CMS that natively supports shortcodes like Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

My Blogger Tricks has recently created a bunch of shortcodes for blogger. You can check them out [here](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/04/blogger-shortcode-plugin.html).

**To create your own shortcodes**

You can create shortcodes for your site with [shortcode.js](https://github.com/nicinabox/shortcode.js)
Here is how you will create an `[item]contents[/item]` shortcode. Run the code to see it in action.

```js
new Shortcode(document.querySelector('body'), {
  item: function(done) {
    return this.contents;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nicinabox/shortcode.js/master/src/Shortcode.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
[item]Sample text[item]
```

Comment: While this might seem convenient, keep in mind that any *JS dynamically inserted content*  will **not** be crawled by search engines if it is not on the page on initial load. That makes this solution suitable only for small, unimportant pieces of content.

Comment: what if we call this script on page load,will it be indexed?

Comment: may be this would help someone-http://downloads.mybloggertricks.com/shortcodes.js

Comment: Upon some research I found that google does index dynamically inserted content now-http://moz.com/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really